# Has anyone managed to install office2007 on windows XP when office 2003 is already installed?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2003, software-conflict

I've tried various ways but all failed.

Is there any way to do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can install and use more than one version of Microsoft Office on a single computer. For example, you can install and use both Microsoft 2007 Office suites and programs and Microsoft Office 2003 on the same computer. However, we do not recommend this.

**Note** Microsoft does not support using multiple versions of Microsoft Office on versions of Microsoft Windows that have Terminal Services enabled. If you want to run multiple versions of Office, disable Terminal Services.

**Installation order**

**Note** This installation order also applies to the Microsoft Office stand-alone products, such as Microsoft Visio.

If you want to install and use more than one version of Office on the same computer, use the following order.

1-Microsoft Office 2000

2-Microsoft Office XP

3-Office 2003

4-2007 Office suites and programs

You must install the earliest version of Office first. For example, if you want to use both Office 2003 and 2007 Office programs on the same computer, install Office 2003 first. You must use this order because of the way in which registry keys, shared programs, file name extensions, and other settings are managed for each version of the Office suites and programs.

**Important** If you remove one of the installed versions of Office, you may have to reinstall the remaining versions of Office in this order for each version to work correctly.

The rest of this article assumes that you installed the versions of Office in this order.

[answer source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928091#top)

Comment: Doesn't work,I decide to re-install my system later...

Comment: @user11671.. I wish I could help more... but h have no time  ..

Comment: You don't have to install the earliest version first. In fact, if you want the default version to be 2003 you must install that last.

Comment: @guitarthrower..ya ... good point...